# Split 100 numbers into N same length parts

Tags: javascript, math

Specify how many numbers you want to show.

E.g. if
you specify 2, the result should be 0 and 100. If you specify 3, the numbers should be 0, 50 and 100. If you specify 4, the numbers should be 0, 33, 67, 100 etc.

There should always be the same length between every displayed number.

Comment: You want N integers (approximately) evenly spaced from 0 to 100, inclusive?

Comment: So the spacing is `100 / (n -1)`? Just plug that into a loop and do a little rounding. This isn't a JavaScript problem until after you've come up with an appropriate algorithm and actually tried to implement it with JS.

Comment: Maybe change title to something like "Split 100 numbers into N same length parts" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for-loop solution:

```js
const run = (max, num) => {
  let result = [];
  let part = max / (num - 1);
  for(let i = 0; i < max; i += part) {
    result.push(Math.round(i));
  }
  result.push(max);
  return (result);
};

console.log(run(100, 4)); // [0, 33, 67, 100]
console.log(run(100, 5)); // [0, 25, 50, 75, 100]
console.log(run(100, 7)); // [0, 17, 33, 50, 67, 83, 100]
```

Comment: This is almost identical to what I came up with so I won't bother posting my function, but note that it doesn't work for `run(100, 7)` or `run(100, 8)` - the results don't include `100`, I assume because of accumulated rounding errors. To get it to work I changed the loop to `<` rather than `<=`, and then added `result.push(max)` after the loop.

Comment: @nnnnnn You are right... I updated the answer, thanks!

Comment: Its 1 am currently. Tired and should probably go to bed, *brainfart* not reading the actual comments...I noticed.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use es6 this is a nice functional one-liner to do it:

```js
const fn = (n, l) => [...Array(n)].map((i, id) => Math.floor(l/(n-1) * id))

console.log(fn(4,100))
console.log(fn(2,100))
```

Of course you can't always have the exact distance between numbers when you want integers — you need to round somewhere when the number doesn't evenly divide.

Answer (score 0):

```
function numbers(number){ 
  var max=100; 
  spacing = Math.floor( max/ (number-1) ); 
  var returnMe = [0]; 
  var cur=spacing; 
  while(cur <= max){ 
    returnMe.push( cur ); 
    cur+=spacing; 
  } 
  return returnMe; 
}
```

Comment: This is close, but it doesn't produce the right results when `number` argument is 4, 7, 8, etc. For one thing it should round the individual numbers in the loop, not the `spacing`.

Comment: yeah I think dhilt answer is what OP is looking for. this always gives exact same increments between #'s which don't always add up to 100.